# How much of a security risk is the mail() function for WordPress websites?

Tags: php, postfix, wordpress

On a VPS with Debian 9 I have a few working https WordPress sites served using Nginx + PHP 7.0 + MariaDB. I also have a mail server with Postfix + Dovecot. Everything is working ok.

Yet, I'm very concerned about the php mail() function that can be used by any php script located inside WordPress' directories to send emails from my server, using the php user, which is "www-data". I've heard horror stories about hackers being able to upload malicious php scripts into WordPress' directories and use them to send thousands of spam emails from that server. How is it possible for a hacker to upload php scripts to WordPress if Nginx is properly configured and all the WordPress directories are owned by the "www-data" user and group with 750 permissions ?

I've tried to deny "www-data" the right to send any emails from the server, by including the "authorized_submit_users = !www-data root" directive in "/etc/postfix/main.cf". This way I can only send emails, from command line or by using the mail() function in php scripts, under the "root" user, while the "www-data" user can't send any emails from the server. The problem is: if I leave the Postfix settings like this, all the WordPress plugins that use the mail() function won't work anymore. I know that in general WordPress plugins such as contact forms or WooCommerce, don't use the mail() function directly, but through the PHPmailer class. This doesn't change the situation. It seems that I can't deny "www-data" the right to send emails from my server.

Then how can I prevent malicious scripts from sending spam under the "www-data" user, using the mail() function, if those scripts ever get into the WordPress directories ?

Answer (score 1):

Hacker usually exploit security hole from any themes or plugins that are present in your WordPress to upload malicious files, and after abuse the server.

See an example [How did the hacker get access to my WordPress upload folder? [closed]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96000/how-did-the-hacker-get-access-to-my-wordpress-upload-folder)

Wordpress got security hole over times, but outdated plugins/themes is a big risk.

Keep your system/wordpress updated is the best advice with wordpress, especially if your nginx is secured correctly.

Comment: nginx/PHP/Debian and their dependencies (like openssl) can also have security vulnerabilities which can in turn lead to a hacked server/application. Securing a server/application is too huge a topic, even though you clearly give very good tips.